# Automated count for attribute table elements

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, count

I need to extrapolate from an attribute table the number of elements divided for categories in an automated way (it's not possible to count them manually cause the number is quite huge, about 10000). In the attribute table there are accomodations (hotels, B&Bs, hostels, etc..) for every municipality of my province and I need to get the number of these accomodations for every municipality.

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **GroupStats** plugin to calculate these things of statistics as it's pretty much a pivot table for QGIS.

You can download/install this from the toolbar:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*

---

**Example**:

Here's an attribute table:

[image: Attribute table]

And here's how to calculate the count of each Inn (or accomodation) per Province:

[image: GroupStats plugin]

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved!! You saved me a lot of time, I love you

Comment: @StefanoCitterio - Haha most welcome! :)